# Variable in for loop is not getting called

Tags: delphi, variables, for-loop

I am using DBXJson to parse a simple json file called `response.json`and show it's contents in a grid, but only the first row of the grid ever gets populated with the data and even though there is more rows/data to display. I am using a custom grid in the code below but I have tried a variation of the below code using the standard stringgrid and it exhibited the same behavior. This is the code I am using to parse the response and show it in my grid.

```
var
  sl: TStringList;
  LJsonArr: TJSONArray;
  LJsonValue: TJSONValue;
  LItem: TJSONValue;
  col, row: Integer;
begin
  col := 0;
  row := 0;

  sl := TStringList.Create;
  sl.LoadFromFile('response.txt');
  LJsonArr := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sl.text), 0)
    as TJSONArray;

  for LJsonValue in LJsonArr do
  begin
    NextGrid1.AddRow();

    for LItem in TJSONArray(LJsonValue) do
    begin
      NextGrid1.Cells[col, row] := TJSONPair(LItem).JsonValue.Value;
      inc(col);
    end;
    inc(row);
  end;
  sl.Free;
end;
```

I suspect that the problem lies in the fact that the `row` variable is out of place and is not getting called and that is causing only the first row to display, but I could be mistaken and I am hoping that a fresh pair of eyes can spot the problem.

Comment: Your indentation is poor which makes it hard for you to reason about your code. Finally, you must learn to debug. Were you to simply step through this code you'd solve the problem easily.

Comment: I blame the indention on SO. In my app it looks normal, but if it makes that much of a difference I will edit it.

Comment: OK, but we cannot tell that. We just have to assume that what you see is what we see. Anyway, my other point stands. Had you stepped through you would have seen col increasing monotonically. Yes, that is obvious from the code now, but if you have a blind spot when reading the code, then inspect its behaviour as it executes.

Comment: I know you are correct about the debugging point. I have only started learning Delphi about 3 months ago and I probably spend more time trying to fix bugs with trial and error than I do actually writing code. I need to find a good "simple" source that I can start to learn from. Thanks for your help again btw.

Comment: I understand. I guessed as much, hence the advice that I offered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `col` must be re-initialised to zero every time you start a new row. So move the initialization of `col` into the outer loop.

```
row := 0;
for LJsonValue in LJsonArr do
begin
  col := 0;
  NextGrid1.AddRow();
  for LItem in TJSONArray(LJsonValue) do
  begin
    NextGrid1.Cells[col,row] := TJSONPair(LItem).JsonValue.Value;
    inc(col);
  end;
  inc(row);
end;
```

I don't know this JSON library but if it allows you to access array elements with random access then a traditional oindexed for loop would lead to cleaner code that the for in loop that you use. In pseudo code:

```
for row := 0 to arr.length do
begin
  item := arr[row];
  for col := 0 to item.length do
    grid.Cells[col,row] := item[col];
end;
```

As a rule of thumb, for in loops are better if you do not need to know the item index. However, as soon as you need to know the item index then traditional indexed for loops are usually to be preferred.

Comment: The JSON library is the one that ships with Delphi (ie. DBXJSON) so I would suppose it would support the 2nd code example you posted. I guess there is only one way to know and that is to try it and see. BTW, thank you for the reply. Moving the col variable out of the inner for loop fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: Yes it is, i thought I had marked your answer as correct. I will do so now.